# Vuejs and Request: Computed property function doesnt display GET JSON value

Tags: json, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue instance.

```
// create a root instance
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:
    {
        album: '',
        artist: '',
        link: '',
        genre: '',
        rating: '',
        genres: ["Memphis Rap", "R&B\Soul", "Pop", "Vaporwave", "Alt-Lat"],
        length: 0
    },
    methods: {
        addAlbum: function (event) {
            this.youtubeAlbumList.push({ album: this.album, artist: this.artist, link: this.link, genre: this.genre, rating: this.rating });
            request.post(
                'http://localhost:3000/album',
                { json: { album: this.album, artist: this.artist, link: this.link, genre: this.genre, rating: this.rating } },
                function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 201) {
                        console.log(body)
                    }
                }
            );
            this.length = this.youtubeAlbumList.length;
            this.album = '';
            this.link = '';
            this.genre = 'Genre';
            this.rating = '';
        }
    },
    computed: {
        albumList:
        {
            get: function () {
                request.get(
                    'http://localhost:3000/album',
                    function (err, res, body) {
                        var info = JSON.parse(body);
                        //.forEach(function(obj) { console.log(obj.id); });
                        return info;
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I'm trying to populate the 'albumList' using Request's get method. The server successfully returns 200 Status Code. In the Developer Tools, I see that the JSON is returning.

[image]

The issue is that the list (albeit short) is not rendering on the page. To render the list, I used the following components:

```
Vue.component('album-component', {
    template: ` 
    <div class="content">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="#" alt="#">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>{{x.album}}</h3>
                        <div class="message-body">
                            <h2>Artist:&nbsp{{x.artist}}</h2>
                            <h3>Link:&nbsp<a v-bind:href="x.link">Link</a></h3>
                            <div>Genre:&nbsp{{x.genre}}</div>
                            <div>Rating:&nbsp{{x.rating}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`,
    props: ['album'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            x:this.album
        }
    }
});


// register
Vue.component('youtube-album-list-component', {
    template: `<div class="row">
                    <album-component v-for="album in albumList" :album="album"> </album-component>         
            </div>`
    ,
    props: ['albums'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            albumList: this.albums
        }
    }
})
```

And the index.html

```
 <div id="app">
      <div>
        <div class="input-group input-group-med">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Album</span>
          <input v-model="album" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
        </div><br>
        <div class="input-group input-group-med">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Artist</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" v-model="artist">
        </div><br>
        <div class="input-group input-group-med">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Link</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Link" v-model="link">
        </div><br>

        <div v-cloak class="input-group input-group-med">
          <select v-model="genre">
          <option v-for="genre in genres" v-bind:values="genre">{{genre}}</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="input-group input-group-med">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Rating</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rating" v-model="rating">
        </div><br>
      </div>
      <button v-on:click="addAlbum" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Left</button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div>
        <div class="page-header result-header">
          <h1>Album list</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <youtube-album-list-component :albums="albumList"></youtube-album-list-component>
    </div>
```

I am trying to pass the computed albumList in to my youtube-album-list-component as prop. Then using that list to create album-components. I'm trying to figure out why although the info variable has an Array that is being returned, it's not being rendered. Any ideas?

Comment: properties, computed or otherwise, cannot be async.

Comment: @MathewJibin how does Vuejs typically handle rendering async data? Would I have to use something like [vue-async-computed](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed) to achieve that goal?

Comment: You'll have to invoke an action to request the async resource or you could do it in any lifecycle event hooks of vue components and then set a backing property. If there are no further processing, you can bind to that property else, you could use a computed property which will automatically update based on the backing property.

Comment: @MathewJibin can you clarify 'backing property' in this context? Something outside the Vuejs instance?

Comment: Comment became too long, so posted an answer. See if that helps you.  Enjoy your Vue tour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could redesign something like this,
Basically you will have a property to hold your list in the `data` property of the component, you update it with ajax, then transform and expose with your computed property.

```
Vue.component('album-component',{
template:"#album-template",
props: ['album']
});

Vue.component('youtube-album-list-component', {
template:"#youtube-list-template",
props: ['albums',"isLoading"]
});



var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:
    {
        album: '',
        artist: '',
        link: '',
        genre: '',
        rating: '',
        genres: ["Memphis Rap", "R&B\Soul", "Pop", "Vaporwave", "Alt-Lat"],
        length: 0,
        albumStore:[],  //This will be your backing store
        limit:2,  
        isBusy:true
    },
    created:function(){
        var me=this;

      //*********REPLACE WITH YOUR AJAX CALL HERE*********

      //moke a ajax request
      setTimeout(function(){
        me.albumStore.push.apply(me.albumStore,[
        {album:"Album 1",artist:"Artist 1",genre:"Pop",rating:4},
        {album:"Album 2",artist:"Artist 1",genre:"Vaporwave",rating:3},
        {album:"Album 3",artist:"Artist 1",genre:"Memphis Rap",rating:5},
        ]);
        me.isBusy=false;
      },3000);
    },
    methods: {
        addAlbum: function (event) { }
    },
    computed: {
        albumList:
        {
            get: function () {
                    //do some for loop or $.map processing here and return the result.
                  var list=[];
                  for(var i=0; i<this.limit && i < this.albumStore.length;i++)
                  {
                    list.push(this.albumStore[i]);
                  }

                  return list;
               }
         }
    }
});
```

A full working [fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/h4385wav/4/). Add functionality is not done, you can build on top of this or adapt it to your liking.

Comment: I think the "backing store" is more usually called an "initial value" which is more straightforward and easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you mean by 'backing store' now. After I posted my question, I began using the 'before created' lifecycle event to make my async call. It worked as well but, not as well as your answer. Last question: I think displaying async data is not an unusual ask of a framework, is it me or is this functionality a weakness in Vuejs?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, My main stack is .net with c#, where it is called a backing field for a property :). This is not a weakness, but this is the usual recommended way, a property with default value, which get updated when new value is available. Computed properties in vue is for transformations on already available data, not for aync operations. For complex scenarios, check the [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex), but if you are a beginner, I'd recommend to first get familiar with the vue way of doing things before considering vuex..

Answer (score 2):

computed property can not be async, you can not call a API from it, as that is asynchronous, you can write that code in methods and it should work:

```
 methods: {
        albumList:
        {
            get: function () {
                request.get(
                    'http://localhost:3000/album',
                    function (err, res, body) {
                        var info = JSON.parse(body);
                        //.forEach(function(obj) { console.log(obj.id); });
                        return info;
                    }
                )
            }
        }
```

If you are adamant or have a strong use case of having this in computed property only, than you can use something like [vue-async-computed](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed) which makes it possible to have computed properties in Vue that are computed asynchronously.

But I am sure using method should be perfectly fine.

Comment: I tried that solution, but after, although the albumList is still get passed into the list component, the get function was not being called. But I'll look into the vue-async-computed module.

Comment: @TYMG any specific reason, you don't want ti use methods as that is the vue way to do it?

Comment: I've tried using the methods that Vue provides but, I think I was using them incorrectly. I'm going to try MatthewJbin's solution since it doesn't require outside libraries.